# Laplacian on squashed spheres

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, riemannian-geometry, harmonic-analysis, laplacian, heat-equation

Is anything known about the Laplacian on squashed spheres $S^{2n-1}_\omega$, where the ambient $C^n$ coordinates satisfy
$$ 1= \sum_{i=1}^n \omega_i |z_i|^2 $$
for fixed real numbers $\omega_i$? for example are the eigenvalues or the heat kernel known?

Comment: Is this distinct from trying to find laplace eigenfunctions on an ellipsoid? If so, I don't think many explicit formulas are known except for n=1 in your case. 

You might find this paper helpful to look at however: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-1-4757-0334-4_9

Comment: @HadrianQuan They are not generic ellipsoids; they are the ellipsoids that are invariant under rotation of each $z_i$ coordinate.

Comment: @HadrianQuan indeed, the $U(1)^n$ symmetry rotation of $z_i$ coordinates makes it non-generic, so perhaps something more is known?

Comment: If i am not mistaken the orbit space of your manifold under the action of $U(1)^n$ is the elipsoid $S^{n-1}_\omega$ (borrowing your notation). While I do not think that explicit formulas can be found, probably you can  explicitly obtain the eigenfunctions of your Laplacian in terms of those of  $S^{n-1}_\omega$ and those of $U(1)^n$. Pretty much like you do by decomposing the usual Laplacian in radial and spherical coordinates.

Comment: @HadrianQuan doesn't the paper that you mention deal with $S^2$? if so, what do we learn about $S^3$?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything written down in higher dimensions, so I think your best bet is to try and follow @AdriánGonzález-Pérez 's suggestion.

Comment: @AdriánGonzález-Pérez my definition was for $2n-1$ namely odd, could you specify what do you mean if $n-1$ is even and in any case how do you get rid of the extra $\omega$'s?